# Is the universal hyperplane section the blowup of the baselocus?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

I think I've heard this statement before but I'd like to make sure it's true.

Let $X$ be a variety and $L$ a line bundle on it.
Take $S < P\left(H^0(X,L)\right)$ to be a linear subspace of the projective space of sections.
Such a thing is called a linear system and produces a (rational) map $X \to P\left( H^0(X,L)^\vee \right)$ to the dual projective space, sending $x$ to $\epsilon_x \colon H^0(X,L) \to k$ which takes $s$ to $\epsilon_x(s) = s(x)$.

The baselocus $A$ of the linear system $S$ is given by $\{x \in X | s(x)=0, \forall s \in S\}$.
The universal family is $H$, given by $\{(s,x) \in S \times X | s(x) = 0 \}$.

My question is: is $H = Bl_A X$?
If so, why?

Comment: Dear user, The morphism will be from $X \to P(S^{\vee})$.  Regards,

Comment: Dear @MattE, could you please expand on your comment a little? I'm confused.

Comment: Dear user, It's just that points of $X$ give functionals on $S$ (well-defined up to a scalar), and so the map is from $X$ to the projectivization of the dual space of $S$.  Actually, I was/am taking $S$ to be a linear subspace of $H^0$, and you were taking it to be a linear subspace of the projectivization of $H^0$, so what I should have said is that the map is to the dual proj. space to $S$.   If you take $S$ to be the entire projectivization of $H^0$, then the map is to the projectivization of the dual of $H^0$, which is what you wrote.  But if you just want to do this (i.e. consider the ...

Comment: ... complete linear system) then there is no need to introduce $S$ at all.  Regards,

Comment: but isn't the map $X \to P(S^\vee)$ you are describing just the composition $X \to P(H^0(X,L)^\vee) \to P(S^\vee)$?

Comment: Dear user, Yes, but the first map may have no base-locus, while the projection to $P(S^{\vee})$ may have a base-locus.  Another way to say it is that the base-locus of $S$ is usually defined as the locus where the map to $P(S^{\vee})$ is not defined, so it seemed a bit odd to me that this map didn't appear in your question.  Regards,

Comment: now I understand your concern, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is *no*.  Consider the case $X = \mathbb P^n$ mapping to itself
by the identity (so $S = P(H^0(X,\mathcal O(1)))$).  Then $H \subset S \times X$ is the set of pairs of a point $x$ and a hyperplane $s$ s.t. $s(x) = 0$ (and $A$ is the empty set).

An easy dimension count gives the dimension of $H$: for each $x$, there is a $\mathbb P^{n-1}$ of hyperplanes passing through $x$, so dim $H = 2n - 1$.  So unless $n = 1$, $X$ and $H$ aren't of the same dimension, and so $H$ can't be a blow-up of $X$.

But in any case, I think you might have been trying to formulate a different statement:

The map $X \to P(S^{\vee})$ is not defined at $A$, so we get a birational map from $X$ to the Zariski closure of the image of $X \setminus A$. Sometimes, this lifts to an isomorphism between $Bl_A X$ and this Zariski closure.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I think I had convinced myself (by writing down equations) that it was true for pencils, ie $S = P^1$) - could it be that for this case it is indeed true by a fluke?